# What does concatMap do?

Tags: haskell

What does `concatMap` do?
I know what `concat` and `map` do.  Is it just both of them put together or is it a completely different function?

Comment: It is behaviorally indistinguishable from `concatMap f = concat . map f`.   I am not sure it is theoretically more efficient either. It's just a convenient combination, I suppose.

Comment: @luqui Because `concatMap` is implemented using `foldr` it can be optimized using the `foldr/build` technique. Hence, yes it is more efficient: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/FoldrBuildNotes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Conceptually, yes, **but** the [actual implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#concatMap) is different:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
concatMap f =  foldr ((++) . f) []
```

Comment: It might be useful to indicate as to why `concatMap` is implemented using `foldr`, the reason being short-cut deforestation using the `foldr/build` technique: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/FoldrBuildNotes

Answer (score 35):

Yes, the `concatMap` function is just `concat` and `map` put together. Hence the name. Putting functions together simply means composing them:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

However `concat` and `map` cannot be put together by simply using function composition because of the type signature of `map`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
       --------    ---    ---
          a         b      c
```

As you can see function composition expects a function of type `a -> b`, but `map` is of type `a -> b -> c`. To compose `concat` with `map` you need to use the `.:` operator instead:

```
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
```

The `concat` function has a type signature of:

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
          -----    ---
            c       d
```

Hence `concat .: map` is of type:

```
concat .: map :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
                 ----------    ---    ---
                     a          b      d
```

Which is the same as that of `concatMap`:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

The `.:` operator itself can be written in terms of function composition:

```
(.:) = (.) (.) (.)

-- or

(.:) = (.) . (.)
```

Hence `concatMap` can be written as:

```
concatMap = (.) (.) (.) concat map

-- or

concatMap = (concat .) . map

-- or

concatMap = concat .: map
```

If you `flip` the arguments of `concatMap` you get the `>>=` (bind) function of the list monad:

```
instance Monad [] where
    return x = [x]
    (>>=) = flip concatMap
    fail _ = []

flip concatMap :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]

>>= :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

This makes it the same as the `=<<` function of the list monad:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]

=<< :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

So now you know everything that there is to know about `concatMap`. It's just `concat` applied to the result of a `map`. Hence the name.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just a typo: "**In** you flip [...]" should be **If** .

Answer (score 11):

Checking [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) reveals:

> ```
> concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
> ```
>
> Map a function over a list and concatenate the results

And that its definition is thus:

```
-- | Map a function over a list and concatenate the results.
concatMap               :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
concatMap f             =  foldr ((++) . f) []
```

Compare the following output from ghci:

```
*Main> concatMap (++"! ") ["one", "two", "three"]
"one! two! three! "
*Main> concat $ map (++"! ") ["one", "two", "three"]
"one! two! three! "
```

Comment: Also if you're wondering *why* it exists, I believe it's because it's the list implementation of `>>=`, just given a different name. :)