# Difference between concatMap f xs and concat $ map f xs?

Tags: haskell

Presumably they do exactly the same thing, `concatMap f xs` and `concat $ map f xs`. Why would I choose one over another?

I imagine it may be an optimization. If so, is this still the case with GHC 7.8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does concatMap do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225396/what-does-concatmap-do)

Comment: Yes, they're conceptually the same, this can be proven with simple write-out of definitions https://gist.github.com/k-bx/e2001663ec755aea4a42 . However, I believe there was a reason concatMap is defined differently than just `concat . map f`, because of fusion optimization to make it run in linear space.

Comment: @KonstantineRybnikov This question is better phrased and has a deeper answer with more to learn from, which is why I've put the duplication the other way around.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is the case that `concatMap f xs = concat (map f xs)` as you suspect. Thus, for correctness purposes you should consider them interchangeable. We can examine their definitions to learn a little more, though.

```
concatMap               :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
concatMap f             =  foldr ((++) . f) []

concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat = foldr (++) []
```

In particular, this means that `concat . map f` expands to `foldr (++) [] . map f`. Now using a thing known as the ["universal property of `fold`"](http://jeremykun.com/2013/09/30/the-universal-properties-of-map-fold-and-filter/) we can see that `foldr g z . map f = foldr (g . f) z` for any (`g`, `z`, `f`) such as the choice (`(++)`, `f`, `[]`) we use above. This demonstrates that `concatMap f = concat . map f` like we want.[0]

So why are they defined differently? Because `foldr ((++) . f) []` is always going to be faster than `foldr (++) [] . map f` since, in a really pathological case, the latter suggests two separate recursions. Due to laziness, it's unlikely that two recursions would ever be performed, though, so what gives?

The real reason is that there are more complex *fusion laws* available to the compiler such as those which combine two sequential `foldr`s or which define interactions between `foldr` and `unfoldr`. These are kind of finicky to use as they depend upon being able to look at the surface syntax of a fragment of code and detect possible simplifications. A *lot* of work goes into getting consistently firing fusion laws.

But one thing we can do is encourage people to use higher order combinators with optimization laws pre-applied. Since `foldr (++) [] . map f` is never going to be faster than `foldr ((++) . f) []` we can take a shortcut and pre-apply the universal law simplification. This will improve the likelihood of fusion laws firing elsewhere to best optimize a list production pipeline.

[0] Why does this law work? Roughly, the universal law of `foldr` states that if you have any function `q` such that `q [] = z` and `q (a:as) = f a (q as)` then that `q` *must be* and *is* `foldr f z`. Since `q = foldr g z . map f` can be shown to have `q [] = z` and `q (a:as) = g (f a) (q as)` then it *must be* a fold like `foldr (g . f) z` like we want.

Comment: Thanks. If I could summarize the reason then, it is because it is hard to write optimization laws that the compiler will reliably apply, so let's help the compiler out with some manual optimization.

Comment: What I don't understand, why not have a rule which transforms `concat $ map f xs` to `concatMap f xs`, then concatMap would not have to be exposed and could stay an internal function used just for optimization.

Comment: There are a slew of laws like that carefully applied across the base codebase for GHC. You can even write your own using the `RULES` pragma. The sticky spot is that these are very difficult to apply in general and it's a major black art to figure out how to properly apply them (!). In general, you also have to be completely certain there are no rough corners to semantics which might change under performance of these rules. If they're to be fully transparent then the abstraction of equational reasoning *cannot break at all*, which requires significant scrutiny.